# How to eliminate a specific row in mysql

Tags: mysql, sql

```
id  manager_id   name

1      1         Tony
2      2         smith
3      2         harry
4      1         jack
5      1         william
6      2         steve
7      2         no name
8      2         john
9      2         no name
```

I used this query for get same last ordered id.

```
select t.* 
  from tablename t 
 where not exists (select 1 
                     from tablename 
                    where manager_id <> t.manager_id 
                      and id > t.id)
```

```
| id  | manager_id | name    |
| --- | ---------- | -----   |
| 6   | 2          | steve   |
| 7   | 2          | no name |
| 8   | 2          | john    |
| 9   | 2          | no name |
```

The above query is working fine. but now my need is Eliminating the specific rows where name = no name. So how to customize the query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below query to eliminate no name,

```
select t.* 
from tablename t 
where not exists (select 1 
                 from tablename 
                where manager_id <> t.manager_id 
                  and id > t.id) and t.name != 'no name';
```

Answer (score 0):

You could use a delete with inner join based  on your query

```
delete t1 from  tablename t1
inner join  (
    select t.* 
    from tablename t 
    where not exists (
         select 1 
         from tablename where manager_id <> t.manager_id and id > t.id
    )

) t2 on t1.id = t2.id 
     and t2.name ='no name'
```

or based  on your comment could be you just want set the value to null
in this case you need  update

```
Update  tablename t1
inner join  (
    select t.* 
    from tablename t 
    where not exists (select 1 from tablename where manager_id <> t.manager_id and id > t.id)

) t2 on t1.id = t2.id
    and t2.name = 'no name'
set t2.name = NULL
```

Comment: But there is no two tables in my database, data stored in just a single table.

Comment: If your query is used   for retrive some (complex) result  .. then  you can use the resulting query as a table  for delete the value you need ..  .. anyway i'm not using two table but just a subqiury on the same table for lead the delete operation  ..

Comment: But I want just eliminate the ex value not to be deleted. How can I do that?

Comment: what mean "eliminate" ?? you want change the value  with  NULL ??  . answer  updated .. with a suggestion